# The difference between two array iterations

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Im just wondering the difference between these array iterations, and why the second one seems to be really rarely used, is something wrong with it?

```
var items = [ /*...*/ ]
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    // Do some stuff with the item
}
```

The second way:

```
var items = [ /*...*/ ]
for (var i, item; item = items[i]; i++) {
    // Do some stuff with the item
}
```

Comment: The difference is that the second won't even run because `i` hasn't been  initialized with a value, unless that's a typo in that case nneonneon is right.

Comment: FWIW, ES5 defines an `.forEach` method for arrays, which seems to be what you would want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first one is guaranteed to *always* iterate through every element.

The second one would stop midway if it encounters some false-like element, such as 0.

Comment: I guess you could counteract this by using `(item = items[i]) !== undefined` but it's a bit confusing and has side effects and ... is ugly.

Comment: Yeah...then you're just better off using the first form. It's idiomatic, it's correct, and it's short.

Comment: Felix is correct, however, an array could possible have undefined values which might serve a purpose

Answer (score 1):

In the second for loop you need to initialize your i variable.

Consider:

```
var items = ["string", false, null, 0, "", {}, []];
```

First loop will loop through the entire array. However, second loop's conditional will evaluate the value assigned to item. The boolean value of this portion would be:

```
!!(item = items[i])
```

valid values such as **null**, **0**, **false**, **""(empty string)** and ***undefined*** will evaluate to false and break. In the array above, you'll break out of the for loop when item is assigned to **false**

Answer (score 0):

In second case the termination condition is somewhat javascript-specific - loop terminates when assignment converted to boolean yields **false**, which happens also on reading array element out of its bounds. This is contrary to other popular languages, where out-of-bouns access to array causes some kind of error and does not guarantee the correct condition for terminating **for** loop. When any programmer with background in other languages than javascript writes iterating loop, he/she probably avoids patters which he knows are incorrect or even dangerous in these languages.

This would be main reason, I think. But other thing is, like mentioned above, that this condition might be **false** even before reaching end of iterated array - for example when assigned element has value of **false**, 0, or any other value, which in javascript implicitly converts to **false**.